# Line 292, Column 10: end tag for element "div" which is not open ; validation

Tags: validation

I've been looking for this extra div for over 5 hours and am at a complete loss. I searched the entire source and cant find this error while trying to validate.

Line 292, Column 10: end tag for element "div" which is not open

http://modernego.info

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at line 104, there is a CDATA close that is missing its closing `>` bracket